# Defining array size at runtime

Tags: c, arrays

I'd read that size specifier is mandatory while declaring an array if it is not explicitly initialized,
but the piece of code given  compiles and runs successfully?

```
main()
{
   int r;
   scanf("%d",&r);
  char array[r];      //memory is not allocated at compile as value of variable is not known
  scanf("%s",array);
  printf(array);





}
```

Comment: C99 supports Variable Length Arrays which makes this work.

Comment: That's C99. Variable-length arrays are illegal in C89, which despite it being 18 years since C99 is still in widespread use.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: VLAs are part of the standard. They are not only supported in C99, but any modern C11 compiler, too.

Comment: Lookup malloc, realloc, free.

Comment: @Olaf Should've phrased "added support"

Comment: @Olaf Nitpick: as of C11, VLAs are "optional". I think C99 was the only standard that specified VLAs as being mandatory.

Comment: FWIW:  Even if you had said, `char array[100];` the memory still would not have been _allocated_ at compile time.  That is because `array` is a local variable.  Even if the _size_ of the allocation is known at compile time, the actual _allocation_ of a local variable does not happen until the function (e.g., `main()` in this case) is called.

Comment: Yep, confirmed (optional): `ISO/IEC 9899:201x: 6.7.6.2 Array declarators`.

Comment: @DevNull: C99 is not C standard (read the foreword of the standard document)! And I wrote clearly "modern C11 compiler". The reason to make VLAs optional - **despite the established practice to keep compatibility up to being idiculous (e.g. not bainning K&R style function declarations)** were C90 compiler vendors to sell their C90 rubbish as "standard C compiler". And guess which company has a major C compiler which never has been able to support C99 since 18 years …

Comment: @Olaf Hmmm, some kind of a software company, that's... Micro? lol. But on the note of C99, is it "not C standard" as in, "it's a language specification, not a standard"? I don't quite follow.  `C11 (formerly C1X) is an informal name for ISO/IEC 9899:2011,[1] the current standard for the C programming language. It replaces the previous C standard, informally known as C99.`

Comment: @DevNull: As you informally state: C99 (resp. the second release of ISO9899) has been canceled with the release of the third release (aka C11). So it is not standard C (since ca. 6 years already).

Comment: @olaf oh, so you mean it is not **the** current standard. That is correct. I misunderstood as you noted that it was not **a** standard. Thanks for clearing this up.

Comment: @DevNull: As there is only one C standard, my statement should have been clear. Of course I did not comment from a historic position.

Comment: @Olaf From a purely linguistic viewpoint, it was not clear. `C99 is not C standard`: isn't even proper English from a grammatical standpoint, unless it was `C99 is not C "standard"` (like saying `scotch "neat"`, as a post-subject qualifier). What would have made sense in this case would be `C99 is not the current C standard`. If it was a standard at one point, and is now superseded by another, it is still indeed a standard, albeit an outdated/deprecated one: further adding to the confusion. With quirks/confusion in the precise use of language, I'll leave it at `the Devil's in the details`.

Comment: @DevNull: I did not mean "standard", but standard. The only thing I missed was the word `the` before >standard<. Using present tense should be enough; it does not imply it never has been. Reading things from a text not explicitly stated is not really a good idea. "it is still indeed a standard" is plain wrong. It **was** a standard, but it clearly has been canceled, so it **is** not standard (anymore). I don't see how that could be wrong.

Comment: @Olaf I agree, the missing `the` is what threw me off. FWIW, your technical contributions are accurate and helpful. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is valid code that makes use of Variable-Length Array feature of C99.

As long as `r` is properly set by `scanf`, it is legal to use it in allocation of `char array[r]`.

There are several issues that need to be addressed, though:

- If `scanf` returns zero, `r` remains uninitialized. Using it for specify array size in a declaration would be illegal.
- If `scanf` read a negative number, using it as array size would be illegal.
- If `scanf` read a number that is too large for your system's automatic memory space, you would run into undefined behavior.

The last point is very important: your system may have enough memory for the array, but not enough space in the automatic memory (often called "stack") to allocate your array. This can result in a crash.

A better approach is to allocate your array dynamically with `malloc`, and `free` it once you are done with it.